# Induction proofs in Big-O notation

Tags: asymptotics, proof-techniques, landau-notation

I'm not sure how go about this question: 
Prove the following inequality. For a correct proof, we require a value of the constant $c>0$ and an $n \in \mathbb N$, such that $\forall n>N : f(x)<c\cdot g(n)$.

$\mathcal O(2^n) < \mathcal O (n!)$.

I'm well aware how to prove $2^n < n!$ using induction, I just don't understand how  one is supposed to find a constant, etc. The only thing that springs to mind here is choosing $N = 4$, since that is when $2^n < n!$ begins to hold. If someone could clarify how I can apply the definition of Big-O notation to solve this, I would be greatful.

Comment: You have a typo in the definition of O: you require $c$ and $N$. You give c (=1) and N (=4) in your post -- what do you think is missing?

Comment: In particular, do you mean O(2^n) is in O(n!)?

Answer (score 2):

We need to inspect the factors after that, since the factors of $n!$ grows linearly while the factors of $2^n$ stays constant. We use the first four factors and the rest of them to formulate the constant factors used for the big-O proof. It is obvious that $2^4 = 16$ while $4! = 24$. However, by observing the factors, we notice $2^n$ has $16$ as a factor and $n!$ has $24$ as a factor for all $n \geq 4$ and we factor out the first four [the first $N$] to clearly highlight that the factorial grows faster.

The factors of $\frac{1}{16} 2^n$ factors out the first $2\cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2$. It is equal to $2\cdot 2\cdot 2\,\cdot \, ... \cdot \, 2$ with $(n-4)$ factors. The factors of $\frac{1}{24}n!$ factors out $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4$ and is equal to $5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7\, \cdot \,... \cdot \, n$, again with $(n-4)$ factors. When $n = 4$ then these factored-out functions are equal to unity. In fact:

- $2\cdot 2\cdot 2\,\cdot \, ... \cdot \, 2\cdot 2 = c_f2^n$ where $c_f = \frac{1}{16}$ whereas
- $5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7\, \cdot \,... \cdot \, (n-1) \cdot n = c_gn!$ where $c_g = \frac{1}{24}$.

The $(n-4)$ factors of $c_f2^n$ is clearly less than the $(n-4)$ factors of $c_gn!$. We arrive at $c_f2^n < c_gn!$. Move the constant factor on the LHS to obtain $2^n < \frac{c_g}{c_f}n! = \frac{24^{-1}}{16^{-1}}n! = \frac{16}{24}n! = \frac{2}{3}n!$.

By inspecting the factors of $2^n$ and $n!$ after the initial four, and knowing that for all $n > 4:\: 2^n < n!$, we factored out the first four terms of each function and inspected the rest to determine $2^n \leq \frac{2}{3}n!$.

The formal definition of big-O states that:

$$\exists c > 0\; \exists N > 0: \forall n\; (n>N) \Longrightarrow f(n) \leq cg(n)$$

In your case, $c = \frac{2}{3} = \frac{16}{24}$ and $N = 4$.

Answer (score 0):

That really makes no sense. Check out e.g. Hildebrand's ["Short course on Asymptotics"](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/lecture-notes/asymptotics.pdf) for details of the meanings and usage of asymptotic notations.

In a nutshell, for typical CS use: $O(f(n))$ is *some* function $g(n)$ that satisfies $g(n) \le c f(n)$ for some (unspecified) positive constant $c$ for all $n \ge n_0$ for some (again unspecified) constant $n_0$. The functions $f$ and $g$ are positive in our usage. It is meant to represent some rough upper bound, in the sense that an "equation" like:

$\begin{equation*}
e^{1/n} = 1 + O(1/n)
\end{equation*}$

means that $e^{1/n}$ is $1 + g(n)$ (here, by the series for $e^x$ it is $g(n) = \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{1}{k! n^k}$) and $g(n) = O(1/n)$ (the sum of the terms after the first is smaller than a constant times $1/n$, as you can check), and $g(n) = O(1/n)$. The convention is that the right hand side is a rougher expression of the left hand side, "$=$" here is *not* equality. For example, you can check that:

$\begin{align*}
3 \sqrt{n} &= O(n^3) \\
17 n^3 &= O(n^3)
\end{align*}$

but that doesn't mean $\sqrt{n} = 17 n^3$. If you use $O(\cdot)$ on the left hand side, make sure the right hand side is rougher. And "$<$" makes no sense whatsoever, any such inequality is subsumed by the $O(\cdot)$ itself.